# expand and shrink text in div - autolength

Tags: css, html

I have in a page a div with an auto width and 30px height in CSS.

When I enlarge the window I want that div to show more words and expand text,  and If take back it hides words or some letters and in the end it put 3 points ... Like in the picture :

How can I do like this in CSS and need to JS ???

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with just css if you get creative  here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HZKMd/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="text">here is some text. here is some text. here is some text. here is some text. here is some text. here is some text. here is some text. here is some text. here is some text. here is some text. here is some text. here is some text. here is some text. here is some text.</div>
    <div id="ellipse"><strong>. . .</strong></div>
</div>​

    #wrapper
{
    position: relative;
}
#text
{
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#ellipse
{
    height: 30px;
    line-height:30px;
    width:20px;
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 3px;
}​
```

or here is an alternate version using jquery to hide and show the ellipse http://jsfiddle.net/HZKMd/1/

add this css class

```
.inner {
    float: left;
}​
```

and include jquery and add these functions

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.inner').width() >= ($('#wrapper').width() - 30)) {
        $('#ellipse').show();
    }
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($('.inner').width() >= ($('#wrapper').width() - 30)) {
        $('#ellipse').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#ellipse').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The periods are visible whether or not the text overflows.

Comment: @sudowned : I didn't understand what you noticed! As user1289347 made overflow:hidden; he can hide scroll bar and the ellipse div helps too to hide text  ....

Comment: Ok I added a jquery version that shows/hides the ellipse, hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text-overflow` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-overflow.

So basically it could look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bbVD7/.